# Does Redis-om for Node.js support Aggregation search?

Tags: redis, node-redis

I just wanted to try aggregation search in node.js application. But I don't know how to do that and also not finding any solution in the related docs.

Just send a code snippet so that I can implement that in my node.js application.

Answer (score 0):

Redis OM doesn't support this yet. It *is* in the backlog but I'm not working on Redis OM full time and there are other features for it with a higher priority.

That said, you can use Node Redis to access the aggregation functions directly. And, there's no reason you can't use the index that Redis OM created.

Assume you have this Schema:

```js
const schema = new Schema('album', {
  artist: { type: 'string' },
  title: { type: 'text' },
  year: { type: 'number' }
})
```

This will create an index named `album:index`. You can use this from Node Redis like this:

```js
const results = await client.ft.aggregate('album:index', '*', {
  STEPS: [{
    type: AggregateSteps.GROUPBY,
    REDUCE: [{
      type: AggregateGroupByReducers.COUNT,
      property: [ 'artist', 'title' ],
      AS: 'albumsPerYear'
    }]
  }]
})
```

Not 100% sure my code that calls `.ft.aggregate()` is perfectly correct as I'm doing it off the cuff. It might well have a bug. But, I think it conveys the idea well enough.